# the pattern of losing electron

Tags: electronic-configuration

The question is the electron configuration of $\ce{Fe2+}$.
Why does it lose the electron of $4s^2$ first instead of losing $3d^2$?
I consider the pattern of the losing electrons in the $p$ orbital. The electron in $p_y$ first but not the $p_z$ in the $Mn$.